# c# Windows form not updating values to SQL database

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a problem in my program that's supposed to store projects given by the user in a database. I'm stuck on the edit project button. After entering new values in the program and hitting the button to save the values everything runs successfully with no errors. The messagebox that says "project edited" appears, I hit ok but the database stays the same. There is no error in the code, the SQL code that gets sent to update the database values is also correct but it doesn't work. Can anyone help with this because I am lost.

Here is the method that creates and executes the SQL code to update the database.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/750h8.png)

Comment: [Never post images of code or data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: and never use concatenated data use prepared statements

Comment: Drop a break point and step through your code.  You should be able to see what's happening, which includes verifying the values you expect at any given point in your code as well as the return from whatever you're doing to update or save values to the database

Comment: See if you can find the contradiction in this sentence of yours: _"There is no error in the code, ... but it doesn't work"_.  Saying "It doesn't work" is pretty useless.  What are the symptoms of your "doesn't-work-ness"? How do you know that _"the SQL code that gets sent to update the database values is also correct"_

Comment: One other thing... The idiom in .NET (and the way the `SqlConnection` class is implemented) is to create a new `SqlConnection` instance every time you talk to the database.  It looks like your `connection` variable is a member of the class.  Instead, you should do something like `using (var connection = new SqlConnection(GetTheConnectionStringFromSomewhere()) { /* the body of your method */ }`

Comment: You're catching _all_ `Exceptions` and then doing nothing with them. You can use `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);` to ensure if there _are_ any errors- you're not just ignoring them.

Comment: Why  are you returning a command from this function?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Wow man that code is wrong in so many ways according to code standards and principles most popular :) but that is not what the question is about directly, though getting you past lost we have to start at the basic tbh:

Suggestions

- when you catch that exception if it comes, show that in a messagebox also you can even add an error icon as part of the .Show command, it's build in.
- Move the connection.Close to the finally block instead of having it replicated
- Consider making an SQL procedure instead and just parse the parameter into that, this code is prone to sql injection that you pose
- Consider not making the procedure and familiarize Yourself with entity framework, it's going to make your life so much easier
- do not concatenate like that, use interpolation or string.Combine or you'll be copying stuff all around on the stack, for each + a new copy one and two into third, it is super inefficient
- When You write the code works and the sql is correct, consider that the outcome is not the desired and therefore it doesn't technically ;) the best and the worst about computers, is that they do what you ask.
- Don't write Your DAL code in the form at all
- Consider  checking your parameters for default values
- You do not have data to say 'project was updated' only 'values were saved', you do not check the old values in the code

Still besides that I do not see why what you wrote wouldn't work, provided the resulting sql is valid in what db you use, but i suppose if you do some of these things the error will present itself

Comment: Why do you think that this function is in the form?

Comment: Don't move the connection.Close to finally block. The connection should be closed by a using block.

Comment: @Mary he use MessageBox.Show so clearly it is in a UI thread at least. See the check in the start of method to see if connection is not null, means he does not dispose the connection, in fact there is no new'ing up of the connection in code snippet at all, so a using statement is not possible without more refactoring ... which i agree could be a good idea, seeing as it is the opening part that takes time, reusing connection makes sense if it is kept open especially.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your feedback, I'll try to address everything you've said. I know my code is written somewhat amateur. I've just started coding in c# almost 2 weeks ago for this project and most of everything I write is from youtube tutorials etc. I've dont some of the things that you've asked me to but the error isn't showing yet. @Flydog57 asked how I know the code I'm sending to SQL is correct. I know because I've added a textbox for the program to paste the code into it before the code gets sent. And when I copy the UPDATE code directly into the SQL it works and the values are updated.

Comment: @EdvaZmaj with that in mind, you're doing great already ;) keep it up, you're on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a connection problem because I have a function that updates only the finishdate of the project and that works completely fine.

Here is the function:

```
public static MySqlCommand FinishProject(int projID, string finishdate) {
    try {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.Open();
            cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", projID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@finishdate", finishdate);
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE `b1c`.`projects` SET `finishdate` = (@finishdate) WHERE (`projectid` = (@value));";
            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
            if (i != 0) {
                MessageBox.Show("Project finalized.");
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show("Catch");
        connection.Close();
    }
    return cmd;
}
```

You can see it's basically the same the only difference are the values.

So it shouldn't be a connection thing because this one works fine I think.

I also don't think it's a problem in the SQL database because all the problems

I've had up until now that had anything to do with the database have shown as errors in visual studio.

If anyone can help I will provide screenshots of anything you need and thank you all once again for trying to help.

Here is the screenshot of the function I've pasted previously so it's easier to look at.

[finishprojectfunction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSrn8.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should show the definition of the database-related data.

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT They're all VARCHAR except the primary key, 'esthours' used to be integer as well but someone suggested to me that I put them all as VARCHAR so I just convert the numbers to string before sending them. Nevertheless I had an error like that previously in another function where the variable definitions in the program didn't match the ones in the SQL database. But that error was showing so I solved that easily.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will work for you or not but my friend had the same problem and it got resolved by adding this line in the connection string Persist Security Info=True; before the user ID.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34490839)